# Read The Last Line Of An Active Logfile With Eggdrop & .tcl

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

Hello i was wondering if its possible to read the last line of a realtime logfile with eggdrop and a .tcl script  im able to read the first part of the logfile but thats it it doesnt read anymore of it

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to put an upper bound on the length of a line of the logfile? If so, it's pretty easy to get the last line:

```
# A nice fat upper bound!
set upperBoundLength 1024

# Open the log file
set f [open $logfile r]
# Go to some distance from the end; catch because don't care about errors here
catch {seek $f -$upperBoundLength end}
# Read to end, stripping trailing newline
set data [read -nonewline $f]
# Hygiene: close the logfile
close $f
# Get the last line
set lastline [lindex [split $data "\n"] end]
```

Note that it's not really *necessary* to do the `seek`; it just saves you from having to read the vast majority of the file which you presumably don't want.

Comment: i do apprciate this very much do i need to add more to this script or just put that in and let it go.  Im about a week into .tcl and eggdrop and still cant make anything work.. Thanks again

Comment: actually it seems ive finally got it hehe  thank u very much for this help