# read the latest line of a serial port

Tags: serial-port, tcl, serial-communication, scilab

I haven't ever written any code in tcl and pretty novice on serial communication, so sorry in advance if my question doesn't make sense.

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934867/replicate-arduinos-serial-monitor-on-scilab-consol) where I want to listen to a serial port and print the updates line by line in SciLab like a normal serial terminal (e.g. Arduino's serial monitor). The [Serial Communication Toolbox for Scilab](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial) has a `readserial` macro ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/sengupta/Scilab-Serial/blob/master/macros/readserial.sci)):

```
function buf=readserial(h,n)
   if ~exists("n","local") then
     N=serialstatus(h); n=N(1)
   end
   TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [read "+h+" "+string(n)+"] cu* ttybuf")
   buf=ascii(evstr(TCL_GetVar("ttybuf")));
endfunction
```

where the `TCL_EvalStr` interprets a string in tcl. So my questin is how I can change the line:

```
binary scan [read "+h+" "+string(n)+"] cu* ttybuf
```

so it only returns the latest non-empty line on the serial port? I would also appreciate if you could eli5 what this line does?

**P.S.1.** So far from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960632/4999991) I tried:

```
 TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [lindex [split [read -nonewline "+h+" "+string(n)+"] "\n"] end] cu* ttybuf")
```

but I get the error message:

> Error: syntax error, unexpected string, expecting "," or )

In SciLab.

**P.S.2.** Defining a new function:

```
function buf=readlnserial(h)
   TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [lindex [split [read -nonewline "+h+"] \"\n\"] end] cu* ttybuf")
   buf=ascii(evstr(TCL_GetVar("ttybuf")));
endfunction
```

leads to error message:

> Undefined operation for the given operands.
>
> check or define function %c_l_s for overloading.

In SciLab terminal.

**P.S.3.** Commands:

```
TCL_EvalStr('[split [read -nonewline '+h+'] "\n"]')
```

or

```
TCL_EvalStr("[split [read -nonewline "+h+"] '\n']")
```

both lead to error:

> Error: Heterogeneous string detected, starting with ' and ending with ".

In SciLab.

**P.S.4.** I think if I use the SciLab command `TCL_EvalFile` instead of `TCL_EvalStr` I can solve the issue above. I just need to figure out how to pass `h` to the tcl script and read back `ttybuf`.

**P.S.5.** I was able to solve the crazy conflict between SciLab string and `"\n"` by using curly brackets instead of double quotation:

```
 TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [lindex [split [read -nonewline "+h+"] {\n}] end] cu* ttybuf")
```

however it is still not giving what I'm lookking for.

**P.S.6.** For those who end up here due to the heterogeneous strings with quotation or double quotation, the correct syntax is `'this '"string'" is inside quotation'`. Basically single quotation before other single quotation or double quotations turn them into literal characters.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's finish taking apart the line:

```
binary scan [read "+h+" "+string(n)+"] cu* ttybuf
```

That's really this:

```
binary scan [read CHANNEL NUM_BYTES] cu* ttybuf
```

where `CHANNEL` is really the name of the Tcl channel that you're reading from (which probably ought to be in binary mode but that's out of scope of the code you're showing), and `NUM_BYTES` is the number of bytes to be read. This is then processed to a list of numbers (written to the Tcl variable `ttybuf`) which are the unsigned bytes that were read.

---

Now, you're wanting to use line-oriented reading. Well, Tcl's `read` command doesn't do that (that's either fixed-buffer or whole-file oriented); you need `gets` for line-oriented reading. (You never want whole-file oriented processing when reading from a serial line; it never reaches EOF. You can do trickery with non-blocking reads… but that's quite complex.)

The `gets` command will return the next line read from a channel, with end-of-line marker removed. We can still use it with binary channels (it's a *little* weird, but not impossible) so that means we can then do:

```
binary scan [gets CHANNEL] cu* ttybuf
```

Converting that back through all that wrapper you've got:

```
function buf=readserialline(h)
   TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [gets "+h+"] cu* ttybuf")
   buf=ascii(evstr(TCL_GetVar("ttybuf")));
endfunction
```

I renamed it, and I removed all the manipulation of `n`; lines are lines, and are not of fixed length. (I wonder whether we can retrieve the string directly without converting through a list of bytes; that would be quite a bit more efficient. But that's secondary to getting this working at all.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get either empty or ` , 776` which again is not correct. What I need is to 1. check if the last character is `\n` 2. if former correct then read between the two last `\n`s. and To fix the conflict between `"\n"` and SciLab string I should use `TCL_EvalFile` and run that part of the command in a tcl script.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I used your suggestion and solved the problem. You may see the result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960839/4999991).

Comment: some discussions [here on Tcl google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/s5wcIAXft1M)

Answer (score 0):

About

[image]

Whatever the string is delimited with `"` or `'`, inserting any `'` or `"`
in it is done by *doubling it*.

So `+"] '\n']"` must be replaced with `+"] ''\n'']"`, and `+'] "\n"]'`  with `+'] ""\n""]'`