# Scilab Serial Communication Timestamp

Tags: timestamp, serial-port, scilab

how is it possible to generate a time stamp whenever the serial port API generates an event to indicate that data was received as well as after newline and/or carriage return characters.

I tried to use readserial function, which will fill the buffer, but i do not know, when each data was actually received.

https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial

```
function buf = readserialline(h)
    tmpbuf = emptystr();
    while tmpbuf == emptystr()
        TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [gets "+h+"] cu* ttybuf");
        tmpbuf = ascii(evstr(TCL_GetVar("ttybuf")));
    end
    buf = tmpbuf;
endfunction
```

see: [read the latest line of a serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935990/read-the-latest-line-of-a-serial-port)

Comment: The question looks unclear to me. Are you expecting such a timestamping feature from the RS232 protocole, or from Scilab after having read the serial buffer (and parsed) its contents?

Comment: Thank you, i expect this by Scilab, after receiving a message which ends by "new line".

Comment: You might add the  [tcl] tag to this thread, since the serial toolbox (and your readserialline code) is based on TCL

Answer (score 0):

I see only 3 possibilities:

1. Either your device is able to send some timestamp on the line,
   in addition to the actual content. Then the timestamp will be built
   on the date *when data are sent*.
   I have never seen this kind of feature for devices i had to manage
   up to now. But why not. Check its user handbook.
2. Either the RS232 standard would have such a timestamping feature,
   that could be enabled. I have never heard nor read anything about that.
   But check the RS232 standard.
3. Or finally, you build an external program that reads the serial line
   and prepends or appends a timestamp based on the *date when the line
   has been read, not when the line has been fed by the device.*

Assuming the 3rd point is yours, then in Scilab you can build a loop calling `readserialline()` and adding a timestamp to its output ; or modify `readserialline()` in the following equivalent way:

```
function [buf, timestamp] = readserialline(h)
    tmpbuf = emptystr();
    while tmpbuf == emptystr()
        TCL_EvalStr("binary scan [gets "+h+"] cu* ttybuf");
        tmpbuf = ascii(evstr(TCL_GetVar("ttybuf")));
    end
    buf = tmpbuf;

    timestamp = sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", getdate()([1 2 6:9]))
    // If you need the fraction of second:
    // d = getdate()
    // d(9) = d(9) + d(10)/1000
    // timestamp = sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%06.3f", d([1 2 6:9]))
endfunction
```

It uses `getdate()` to return the current date as numbers, and then `msprintf()` to format the numerical date into a string:

```
--> sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", getdate()([1 2 6:9]))
 ans  =
  "2023-02-18 12:06:13"
```

But then, **this timestamps data not when the *buffer receives* them, but when the *program reads* the buffer. There may be seconds, minutes, hours or more in between!**

Comment: Thank you for your kind suport.
Do you know Hyperterminal or Coolterm? It says that each message received ending by <cr> while get a timestamp. 
"CoolTerm generates a time stamp whenever the serial port API generates an event to indicate that data was received as well as after newline and/or carriage return characters."
https://forums.the-meiers.org/viewtopic.php?t=489


I would like to have this featuere in Scilab. I need to know exactly the time difference between each value received by the device.
The device is constantly sending messages without a timestamp.

Comment: So, as Hyperterminal or Coolterm, you need to make Scilab continuously reading the port -- for instance through `readserialline()` called in an infinite `while` loop --. This will be a modal, "blocking", process: no way to do anything else in parallel in the Scilab console.